# Keyboard arrow keys navigation with Cbp image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, keyboard, slideshow

I'm trying to edit the [CBP Slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/) to allow the keyboard's arrow keys to navigate the slideshow.Keyboard keys are not working for the slider

I have tried the below code, but not working for my requirement:-

```
<script>

    function handleKeyboardNav(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var kc = e.keyCode;
        if (kc == 37) nslider.prev();
        if (kc == 39) nslider.next();
    }

    function bindKeyDownListener() {
        if (document.addEventListener)
            document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyboardNav, false);
        else if (document.attachEvent)
            el.attachEvent("onkeydown", handleKeyboardNav);
    }
         bindKeyDownListener();

</script>
```

any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) which is a simple library for handling keyboard shortcuts. Remember that you need to use `return false;` after calling your selected function in the bind method to prevent the default action of the keyboard key being performed.